# Pentaho integration in web site

Tags: analytics, pentaho

Hi In my website I add one tab name as "Analytic" when user click on that link I want to shows following video interface to user 
[Click here for video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsrHGR5kTqE)

My website developed in structs and I want to use pentaho in my web sites. If any one knows how to integrate pentaho analytic in website? I used pentaho community version.

Comment: so whats the prob , what have you tried ??

Comment: Hi, actually I am beginner in pentaho when I used pentaho according pentaho steps there mentioned that for starting pentaho use start.sh and in browser open locahost:8080 port it work fine but I want to shows above video data analysis report in my web page how I integrate same things in my web page so user can manged or searched his/her criteria and generate report for viewing.

Comment: you need to modify the jsp page accordingly

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid can you provide any tutorial link or video ?

Comment: dont remeber but there was somebody named raju , search for him